# Use of (INDEX(0)) in sql query

Tags: sql-server-2008, indexing

I run this query on SQL Server 2008:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Dealers WITH (INDEX(0))
WHERE ID = 'rrsdsd'
```

But the execution plan shows that it used the clustered index of the table.

[image]

Why so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are telling SQL Server is to execute the query not using any indexes. Therefore, I would expect the query plan to show the clustered index being used (because that is your data), but a scan being done and not a seek. Is this the case?

According to the documentation:

If a clustered index exists, INDEX(0) forces a clustered index scan and INDEX(1) forces a clustered index scan or seek.

This is exactly what you are seeing.

Comment: Yes..please see the attached screen shot in the question.

Comment: @Learner - So what you are seeing is exactly what should be happening. A hint of INDEX(0) forces an clustered index scan. This is what you are seeing and what is expected.

Comment: because that is your data?? Can you please explain it a bit..And then how can I run a query which will use NO INDEXES at all?

Comment: When you have a clustered index, the data in your table is actually stored in the clustered index. So, your clustered index IS your data. You can simply delete your clustered index. Then you have a table that's called a heap. But, the effect will be exactly the same. A scan will still be done. Whether you're scanning a table with no clustered index or scanning a table with a clustered index, the end result is the same. You are still doing a scan. Meaning, every row in the table is examined to see if it satisfies the query.

Comment: If I understood it correctly..Either we have a clustered index or not..Data is only in one place..either sorted or not..right?

Comment: Yes, you either have a clustered index or you don't. If you do, all your data is stored in the clustered index and in order of the clustered index.

Comment: Thanks..I can imagine it now :)

Answer (score 2):

Documentation says it all...

> INDEX (index_value [,... n ] ) | INDEX = ( index_value) The INDEX()
>   syntax specifies the names or IDs of one or more indexes to be used by
>   the query optimizer when it processes the statement. The alternative
>   INDEX = syntax specifies a single index value. Only one index hint per
>   table can be specified.
>
> **If a clustered index exists, INDEX(0) forces a clustered index scan** and INDEX(1) forces a clustered index scan or seek. If no
>   clustered index exists, INDEX(0) forces a table scan and INDEX(1) is
>   interpreted as an error.
>
> If multiple indexes are used in a single hint list, the duplicates are
>   ignored and the rest of the listed indexes are used to retrieve the
>   rows of the table. The order of the indexes in the index hint is
>   significant. A multiple index hint also enforces index ANDing, and the
>   query optimizer applies as many conditions as possible on each index
>   accessed. If the collection of hinted indexes do not include all
>   columns referenced by the query, a fetch is performed to retrieve the
>   remaining columns after the SQL Server Database Engine retrieves all
>   the indexed columns.